# Simple world time clock in Desktop using local host as base for computation

Tags: timezone, desktop-application, offline

I have been searching the web for some simple world clock program that will run in the background without the use of internet connection. Instead I found this site using Google search: http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/info/global.htm

Now I would like some opinions on which language would fit best to the program I would like. Basically it will look like a simple 2 column table. Column 1 will be the time zone and column 2 as current time according its respective zones. It will just continuously run in the background while not consuming too much memory. The local time of the computer will be used as the base.

Again this will be an **OFFLINE world time zone, so a desktop-application.**

Features may include these as well but not necessary:

1. The time will be at 24 hour format to make it easier to read (well I find it easier and might be necessary).
2. Transparency setting.
3. Always on top.

I have learned some basic programming languages but don't know how to make this project in actuality since I haven't touched on the "visual" parts of the languages. I've seen some applications built on java but I haven't learnt it yet. I know basic python and basic C++.

Here's what I think it will look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkZNG.jpg
Just make it longer vertically so every time zone will fit.

Answer (score 1):

First some notes. The page you link to show 24 timezones. This is for all practical use a lie. There are isn't 24 time zones, there are hundreds. 408, to be specific, of which several have more than one name, so there are 548 different names. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones If you are on Windows, you might want to use Windows internal registry of time zones. It has fewer, but still hundreds of timezones.

Listing all of those is not practical. You will need a way for the user to select what time zones he wants to display. Many operating systems time/date widgets allow this already.

If you still want to do this application, then you can do this in any language whatsoever, more or less. Since you know basic Python I'd recommend you do it in Python, using [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) as the time zone library. As for GUI support, [Kivy](http://kivy.org/) looks cool, and is very portable, even supporting iOS and Android.

Also note that time zones change often, so that you probably need to update your application a couple of times per year, just to get the latest time zone definitions. You can get around that in various more or less complicated ways. But I'd leave that for overcourse at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the input.

I've thought over what you said and I think I was misunderstood. I basically would like to have a translation of everything to GMT. Say we make it 3 columns, the first would be a translation to other world timezone (say label "CST"). The second would be a GMT equivalent (label "GMT -6" for CST). The third would be the current time in that timezone (changes every second). This is what I meant by "simple".

Comment: @redsel: That is indeed something most operating systems clock widgets do not do, so that could be a useful tool. But it changes nothing else I said. There is, by the way, four different time zones called "CST". They are more accurately named * America/Chicago
* Australia/Canberra
* Asia/Shanghai
* Asia/Taipei

Comment: that's right. Thanks again. Reading pytz is making me confused right now so I'll try again later.